# C# - I can't access my Master Page's img tag's src attribute from my code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, src, runat

```
<td>
    <a runat="server" href="~/url.aspx">
        <img src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/image1") %>" id="submissions"
        border="0" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('submissions','','<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/image2") %>',1)"></a></td>
```

When I try to run this code with runat="server" added to my img tag, I get a Parser Error that says "Server tags cannot contain <%...%> constructs." The C# code I tried in my code behind's Page_Load is:

```
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("submissions"))
    submissions.Attributes["src"] = "~/images/image3";
```

The goal is to highlight the part of the navigation bar that corresponds to the page the user is already visiting. The problem is that it doesn't allow me to access the img tag's src attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<img src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/image1") %>' id="submissions" ...
```

Pay attention to ' not "

If you need access to this tag from CodeBehind - the easiest way is to replace `<img/>` to `<asp:Image runat="server" id="submissions"/>` and in Master codebehind access by ID, but in child page - using

```
Image submissions = (Image)this.Master.FindControl("submissions");
```

Comment: It says that "submissions" doesn't exist in the current context. If I add runat="server" to the img tag in Main.master, then I get the Parser Error that I mentioned before.

Comment: Am I understood you correctly? Img tag is in MasterPage. You need to access it from child page?

Comment: The Img tag is in MasterPage. I'd like to access the Img tag in MasterPage.cs, or the child page if that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the modification, but I'm still getting a parser error. It says that the server tag is not well formed. :(

Comment: Yep. It is not closed. Add </img> before </a>

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to right escaping here:

```
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('submissions','','<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/images/image2") %>',1)"

onmouseover="MM_swapImage('submissions','','<%= ResolveClientUrl(\'~/images/image2\') %>',1)"
```